# Angular 2+: Get child element of @ViewChild()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, viewchild

How can I access the child elements (here: `<img>`) of `@ViewChild()` in Angular 2+ without explicit declaration?

**In template.html**

```
<div #parent>
  <!-- There can be anything than <img> -->
  <img src="http://localhost/123.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**In component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('parent') parent;

public getFirstChild() {
   this.firstChild = this.parent.? //
}
```

The aim is, to be able to create a universal component that uses:

```
<div #parent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

So the child elements of `#parent` need to be accessible without explicit declaration.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `nativeElement` property of the `ElementRef` given by `ViewChild` to get the corresponding HTML element. From there, standard DOM methods and properties give access to its children:

- element.children
- element.querySelector
- element.querySelectorAll
- etc.

For example:

```
@ViewChild("parent") private parentRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

public getChildren() {
  const parentElement = this.parentRef.nativeElement;
  const firstChild = parentElement.children[0];
  const firstImage = parentElement.querySelector("img");
  ...
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgw8lx) for a demo.

Comment: Great, thanks!
Might there be an additional Angular way to access the child elements?

Comment: The "Angular way" would be with template reference variables, but I don't know if they can be used in transcluded content.

Comment: Awesome! This was the only thing I found to let me select a dynamically generated component of an unknown type injected in an ng-container with *ngComponentOutlet inside my parent component.

Answer (score 3):

use `ViewChildren` instead which gets all elements with same tag.

```
@ViewChildren('parent') parents: QueryList<any>;
```

To convert those elements to array:

```
const arr = this.parent.toArray();
```

Choose first element:

```
const el = arr[0]
```

Access child html of first element:
const innerHtml = el.nativeElement.innerHtml;

Comment: But this doesn't access the <img>, does it? I need to access the **child** of #parent

Comment: Why you do not access img directly instead of through parent. If you have strong reason for than then you can use innerHtml to access child. const el = arr[0].nativeElement.innerHtml

Comment: As I mentioned, the parent has dynamic content. So I don't want to have an explicit accessor for the content.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you need only one and first child.

> this.parent.nativeElement.firstChild

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div #parent>
  <span id="child">
</div>
```

TS

```
 @ViewChild('parent',{static:false}) parentDiv:ElementRef
 this.parentDiv.nativeElement.firstChild
```

You can check this out if you want do any operations in it [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)