# Obtaining child elements from component tags

Tags: angular

I was wondering if such mechanism is allowed in Angular:

```html
<app-form-general>
  <p>Hello</p>
</app-form-general>
```

Angular compiles it and shows `app-form-general`, but I can't find a way for it to process child element. I wanted to create component with dynamic number of elements, but sadly I guess it's not something obtainable. Or is there something to process internal child data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+: Get child element of @ViewChild()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828448/angular-2-get-child-element-of-viewchild)

Comment: have you heard about `<ng-content>`?

Answer (score 1):

You should do in your component 'app-form-general'.

Where ever in your component, you want to show the child component. Add this 'ng-content'

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-any-component', // not app-root
  template:  '<button (click)="add">   
                 <ng-content></ng-content>
              </button>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AnyComponent{

}
```

// Other component

```
 <app-any-component> Hello </app-any-component>
```

[Here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kq1cco)

Comment: Although this is the answer, I think some more clarification than 'Where ever in your component, you want to show the child component. Add this'. Explain `ng-content` a little bit maybe? Refer to some documentation.

Comment: the root of the app cannot use 'ng-content', so perhaps use another example component to make it more clear :)

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes, agreed. We cannot use in app-root. It's the same component which he is using.