# How to set innerText value for li using query selector in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular8

Tried to set innertext to third li of ul in angular 8 but not working.How to select ul and third li using queryselector to find the solution

app.component.html:

```
<tr>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Test 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Test 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Test 3</span></li>
    <li><span>Test 4</span></li>
    <li><span>Test 5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</tr>
```

app.component.ts:

```
setInnertext(event){ 
    let getTr=event.target.closest('tr');
    getTr.querySelector('.wrapper').querySelector('ul').querySelector('li:nth-child(3)').innerText="New Name";
  }
```

Comment: You have to use `ìnnerHTML`instead of `innerText`.

Comment: use [@ViewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Comment: @reporter No, you don't.

Comment: @reporter: Already tried but not working

Comment: @NilaVaani Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828743/7124761

Comment: There's no need to string separate `.querySelector()` calls together. You can just create a more specific selector. Also, use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText`. `.textContent` is more modern and more standard: `getTr.querySelector('.wrapper > ul:li:nth-child(3)').textContent = "New Name";`

Comment: @ScottMarcus:  Not working

Comment: I think you need to double-check what `getTr` is actually returning. What element(s) have you set your event handler up on in the first place? `closeset()` looks for ancestor elements that match the selector, so in your case your handler would have to be set up on something inside of the `tr` in order to locate the `tr` that it is within.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: This line only working:getTr.querySelector('.wrapper > ul') But if use ul:li:nth-child(3) not working

Comment: Sorry, that should have been: `getTr.querySelector('.wrapper > ul > li:nth-child(3)').textContent = "New Name";`

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Getting error like : can not set property 'textContent'

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Again, what element have you set the event up on? What element is `getTr`? I have a feeling that it isn't what you think it is?

Comment: @ScottMarcus:Check my question inside li span tag is there

Comment: No it's not. I don't think you understand what I'm asking. Where have you set `setInnertext` up as an event handler? Just after the `let getTr...` line, add `console.log(getTr)` and tell us what that reports.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Now working good..Thanks

Comment: @ScottMarcus: How to remove li class name? removeClass('classname') not working

Comment: `elementReference.classList.remove("className")`